# The relationship between \$\beta\$ and \$I_C\$, \$V_{CE}\$

Tags: transistors, bjt

It was pointed out to me recently that I don't have a good understanding of the varying relationship between a BJT's \$\beta\$ parameter (or \$h_{FE}\$) and the operating point of the transistor.

Typically you would think that this sort of information comes from the datasheet, but when you go to a common one like a 2N2222, you get a mixed-up sampling of random operating points:
[image: hFE data for a 2N2222]

I did learn that you cannot rely on \$\beta\$ or \$h_{FE}\$ as a design parameter which can vary with temperature and age (up to around 50% to 200%), but the relationship between \$\beta\$ and operating point is not something that any class covered.

What general trends and rules of thumb are used to make sense of the varying \$\beta\$ value? What are the factors and considerations for the varying \$\beta\$ when you are designing transistor circuits?

Comment: where did you get that data from?  an \$I_C\$ of 500 mA surely seems like enough to totally fry a 2N2222.  this appears to be a [typical curve](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/ietron/loadline2.gif) for that device.

Comment: From the Fairchild datasheet. The (4) note says that this is a pulsed measurement.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson 2n2222s are rated to 700mA, the plastic cased PN2222 to a bit less, but yeah they're not good for 5W dissipation

Comment: Wikipedia says 0.8A so so long as you keep them saturated when on they don't dissipate much energy.

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/biasing-calculations/

Comment: The influence of large tolerances for active devices (transistors, opamps,..) are effectively reduced - as far as the behaviour of the whole circuit is concerned - applying negative feedback.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that you can't rely on a specific value of beta - ever - and so you design your circuit so that its performance is largely independent of beta and test (usually via simulation) for correct performance at both ends of the likely range.

Answer (score 1):

> What general trends and rules of thumb are used to make sense of the varying β value? What are the factors and considerations for the varying β when you are designing transistor circuits?

The answer to the first question. You can use either negative feedback, or you can force a certain parameter set, and allow for variation. An example of negative feedback is using emitter degeneration resistors in Common Emitter amplifiers. An example of forcing parameters is using a current source to bias the transistor and then simply ensuring that there's enough current and voltage on the input to keep it linear. (which isn't hard for most signal level transistors)

As for factors and considerations for varying β, I've never personally bothered to take any other than "use the worse case β." If the β, is higher, then you get less current draw from the source: Win. If it's the worst, then no harm no foul. Also, taking the time to calculate Rin and Rpi never hurt either.

Finally, at the end of the day, if β is really important, Mosfets and Jfets have an almost infinite β (~10^9 -> ~10^12). See if that's more what fits your needs. After all, it's not like we've found some transistor that is all encompassing and perfect in every scenario.

Comment: Interesting observations -- a lot of this was given as standard advice when designing amplifiers in engineering school (just assume \$\beta\$ is more or less uncontrolled) I've since gotten far more sophisticated in other areas (embedded, motor control) but designing BJT circuits is not something that comes up a lot! In this case I am trying to fill in a gap that has come up.

Comment: @Daniel,  β is absolutely uncontrolled.  β is just a byproduct of design, random variation in process, and bias. Most people use BJT's as switches, where as I find that they actually work better as linear devices. Mosfets make better switches, but those gate voltages are annoying to deal with. Such is life.

Comment: "Most people use BJT's as switches" how naive!

Comment: @Andyaka, On this website, I see a lot of H bridges with BJTs. A Lot of people talking about using BJTs in saturation as a "switch." And so on and so forth. Nice to see you found my comment humorous. I know it must especially tickle that funny bone as an Analog Engineer.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I went looking for the graphs in the Fairchild data sheet I new this data sheet was insufficient. It seems that several manufacturer's are getting lazy (or incompetent) at giving the full story in the data sheet on jelly-bean transistors these days. So I went for the ON semiconductors [**data sheet**](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF) and this contains more information such as: -

[image]

Although not perfect you can get a lot of performance information about the device just in this one graph.

But, the bottom-line for me is a good simulation model, so if you want to try and figure out how good a particular transistor is in a particular circuit then use something like LTSpice.